# Understanding Flow of Multiple Bash Outputs

Tags: python, bash, unix, io-redirection

I'm having trouble understanding the flow of this command:

```
$ cat epron-jpron.data | ./em.py epron-jpron.viterbi >epron-jpron.probs 2>epron-jpron.logs
```

I understand that `epron-jpron.data` is `stdin` for `em.py`, but how does `em.py` interact with the outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `cat` reads file epron-jpron.data.
2. `cat`'s stdout is redirected (by `|`) to `./em.py`'s stdin.
3. Stdout of `./em.py` is redirected (by `>`) to file epron-jpron.probs.
4. Stderr of `./em.py` is redirected (by `2>`) to file epron-jpron.logs.